# Export a customised object in AngularJS with TypeScript

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, model, typescript

I've got the service `MessageService` which resides in the same module as the implemention of the class `ClientMessage<T>`.

What is the easiest way to access this class via an independent controller which already injects the `MessageService` class?

Is there an easier approach which comes closer to NodeJS's `import service = require('MessageService')` solution?

What's best practise for this? Defining those message related model classes in a seperate file and load them via dependency injection?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code your are using the old syntax (`module` keyword) for internal modules, [the new syntax](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#namespace-keyword) uses the `namespace` keyword:

```
namespace Common.Services {
 // ...
}
```

Since [the release of TypeScript 1.5](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#es6-modules) you can use the new ES6 module syntax.

In your example, you need to remove the `module Common.Services {` part and the `export` keyword before interfaces and classes. Then at the bottom of the file you can use:

```
export { IMessageService, IMessage, ClientMessage, MessageService };
```

Then from an independent controller in a file named `x_controller.ts`:

```
import { MessageService, ClientMessage } from "somefile.ts";
var a = new ClientMessage<string>();
var b = new MessageService();
```

Once you have migrated your code to the ES6 module syntax, if you are working with Node.js, you can compile the modules into CommonJS modules using the `--module commonjs` [compiler option](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Compiler-Options).

You can learn more about ES6 modules [here](http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html). You can learn more about the difference between internal and external modules [here](http://www.codebelt.com/typescript/typescript-internal-and-external-modules/).

Comment: Awesome - unfortunately, I am using a generator for this project so it won't be that easy to push the whole codebase to this new convention.